# I want to omit addressLine1 if element attribute has Attention

Tags: xml, xslt

If the type attribute of the Address element = “Standard With Attention” I do not want to display AddressLine1. Instead I want to only display AddressLine2, AddressLine3 and AddressLine4.
**My output**

**Attn: Michael, 134 W Broadway ST NW, APT 3B, Washington, DC, 12345**

Expected output:
**134 W Broadway ST NW, APT 3B, Washington, DC, 12345**

**My xml**

```
<ProtectedAddresses>
    <Address InternalAddressID="1618613567" Type="Standard With Attention">
        <AddressLine1>Attn: Michael</AddressLine1>
        <AddressLine2>134 W Broadway ST NW</AddressLine2>
        <AddressLine3>APT 3B</AddressLine3>
        <AddressLine4>Washington, DC, 12345</AddressLine4>
        <Attention>James</Attention>
       </Address>
</ProtectedAddresses>
```

**Xslt**

```
<xsl:for-each select="Addresses/Address">
   <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/DCProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
     <xsl:for-each select="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
       <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">, </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
     <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace `<xsl:for-each select="AddressLine1 | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">` with `<xsl:for-each select="AddressLine1[not(../@Type = 'Standard With Attention')] | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">` you construct the node-set with only three elements if the condition `../@Type = 'Standard With Attention'` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is rather confusing, because you only show us a partial XML. As a result, it is difficult to give an accurate answer because the context is not clear enough, and it is impossible to test the given answer against your input.

IMHO, you should be using a **key** instead of this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/DCProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">
```

Now, to address your question (as best as possible): to exclude `AddressLine1` under some circumstances, you should append it with a *predicate* -  i.e. something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="AddressLine1[not(../@Type='Standard With Attention')] | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | AddressLine4">
```

This will work if - as it seems - the condition exists in the parent element of the actual `AddressLine1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked as I used same code you provided as provided by Martin Honnen. I am not sure how to use a Key as you suggested instead of using my code `<xsl:for-each select="ancestor::ProtectionOrder/ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty/DCProtectionOrderPartyAdditional/ProtectedAddresses/Address[@InternalAddressID=current()/@InternalAddressID]">`

Comment: @Angela I suggest you post another question regarding that, with a minimal but complete example of your XML.